# Chrome CSS background colour issue

Tags: google-chrome, css

Hi
I have a meter bar as seen on http://ourplasma.org but it is having a slight issue along the right side where the background is getting clipped as seen in http://d.pr/1UgN

It works fine in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `#meter`, remove `width: 100%`.

Looks "the same" in Firefox, and fixes it in Chrome.